# Kotlin coroutine support in Spring MVC using Spring Boot 2.2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I have a traditional spring MVC (servlet stack) application that uses WebClient from `spring-boot-starter-webflux` package. in recent Spring Boot 2.2.0 release, Kotlin Coroutine support has been added for the reactive stack (webflux). I am wondering if it is feasible to use Kotlin Coroutines with WebClient when used in (servlet stack) Spring MVC.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.4.0 finally supports Kotlin Coroutines in servlet stack - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/languages.html#coroutines

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning about Spring Webflux and WebClient.  This article says it can be done, though I haven't tried it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kotlin-coroutines.

I *have* been trying something like the controller side from that article but don't have it working :-(